# Three level PWM modulator circuit feedback simulation

Tags: amplifier, pwm, feedback, modulation, class-d

I'm trying to design a three level PWM circuit with feedback and i'm struggling to understand the feedback aspect.

The design is based on [this design by Texas instruments](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau508/slau508.pdf) and modified to suit three level.

[image]

The design works if B is not added to the feedback loop.

[image]
[image]

As soon as i connect B to the 10k resistor, the circuit completely deteriorates.

[image]
[image]

I'm certain I don't understand feedback properly and am hoping someone can tell me what the issue is here or can direct me to relevant feedback literature.

The PWM is for a class D amp and i'm taking the feedback before the switching stage currently but intend to take pre filter feedback later on. Am I okay in assuming the feedback in this circuit is a good indication of what it would be like in a full amplifier circuit minus the switching error?

Comment: Post **your** schematic?  Clearly label this "B" you're talking about.  There's a lot of schematics in that app note, it's not clear which one you're talking about.  It also appears that \$10\mathrm{k\Omega}\$ is the designer's favorite value, so it's not clear which \$10\mathrm{k\Omega}\$ you're talking about, either.

Comment: Apologies, completely forgot to add schematic.

Comment: Is your sine wave centered around 2.5V?

Comment: Adding B to the feedback loop effectively cancels A, and causes you to run open loop (ish).  Try adding B not instead.

Comment: Seems to get better but still not correct: https://imgur.com/a/MD8pmOP
Sine wave input is is 2v signal with zero offset. Offset is added with U2 and vref.

Comment: @TimWescott I doubled the feedback resistors to 20k and the signal looks normal apart from some deformation around the crossover point: https://imgur.com/a/8IeerfK. Do you know what the cause of this is? And do you have any advice regarding my second question when implementing feedback in a complete amplifier? I intend to take feedback from both sides of the speaker before the filter.

Comment: I think that picking it off as close to the speakers as possible is good (right before some passive filtering counts, as far as I'm concerned).

Comment: I don't believe that is crossover distortion.  I believe that is just your filter interacting with the PWM to give you a fairly straight line.  If you want to know about distortion you should use your simulator's FFT function (assuming it has one) to measure.